# Groupby Diff - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I would like to find the difference between columns in Multi-index, I have three dimensions, the Family, the Date, and the Client, in the goal is to have new columns with the difference by rows with Client,Date and Family in Multi-index.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    data = {
        'Family':{
            0: 'Hugo',
            1: 'Hugo', 
            2: 'Hugo', 
            3: 'Hugo'},
        'Date': {
            0: '2021-04-15',
            1: '2021-04-16',
            2: '2021-04-15',
            3: '2021-04-16'},
        'Client': {
            0: 1,
            1: 1,
            2: 2,
            3: 2},
        'Code_Client': {
            0: 605478.0,
            1: 605478.0,
            2: 605478.0,
            3: 605478.0},
        'Price': {
            0: 2.23354416539888,
            1: 2.0872536032616744,
            2: 1.8426286431701764,
            3: 0.3225935619590472}
        }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    pd.pivot_table(pd.DataFrame(data), values='Price', index=['Code_Client'],columns= 
    ['Family','Date', 'Client'])
```

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for the difference for Price grouped by the `Family` and `Date` and `Client`. Your formulation of the problem was somewhat unclear and you didn't post an expected output.  I changed your dataframe slightly to add a family to make the solution more visible.

```
data = {
        'Family':{
            0: 'Hugo',
            1: 'Hugo', 
            2: 'Victor', 
            3: 'Victor'},
        'Date': {
            0: '2021-04-15',
            1: '2021-04-16',
            2: '2021-04-15',
            3: '2021-04-16'},
        'Client': {
            0: 1,
            1: 1,
            2: 2,
            3: 2},
        'Code_Client': {
            0: 605478.0,
            1: 605478.0,
            2: 605478.0,
            3: 605478.0},
        'Price': {
            0: 2.23354416539888,
            1: 2.0872536032616744,
            2: 1.8426286431701764,
            3: 0.3225935619590472}
        }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    pd.pivot_table(pd.DataFrame(data), values='Price', index=['Code_Client'],columns= 
    ['Family','Date', 'Client'])
```

As you can see, I added the Victor family. So, you dataframe looks like this:

```
Family        Date  Client  Code_Client     Price
0    Hugo  2021-04-15       1     605478.0  2.233544
1    Hugo  2021-04-16       1     605478.0  2.087254
2  Victor  2021-04-15       2     605478.0  1.842629
3  Victor  2021-04-16       2     605478.0  0.322594
```

To add a column of differences by groups, I suggest you do the following:

```
df =  df.set_index(['Family', 'Date','Client']).sort_index()[['Price']]
df['diff'] = np.nan
idx = pd.IndexSlice

for ix in df.index.levels[0]:
    df.loc[ idx[ix,:], 'diff'] = df.loc[idx[ix,:], 'Price' ].diff()
```

The first step indexes you variables (the ones you want to group by) and create an empty (or filled with `nan`) column of difference. The second step populates it by the differences between rows, by groups.

This returns:

```
                       Price      diff
Family Date       Client                    
Hugo   2021-04-15 1       2.233544       NaN
       2021-04-16 1       2.087254 -0.146291
Victor 2021-04-15 2       1.842629       NaN
       2021-04-16 2       0.322594 -1.520035
```

If you are unhappy about the `nan`, do this:

```
df =  df.set_index(['Family', 'Date','Client']).sort_index()[['Price']]
df['diff'] = np.nan
idx = pd.IndexSlice

for ix in df.index.levels[0]:
    df.loc[ idx[ix,:], 'diff'] = df.loc[idx[ix,:], 'Price' ].diff().fillna(0)
```

I added `.fillna(0)` to the `diff()`statement. It returns:

```
                     Price      diff
Family Date       Client                    
Hugo   2021-04-15 1       2.233544  0.000000
       2021-04-16 1       2.087254 -0.146291
Victor 2021-04-15 2       1.842629  0.000000
       2021-04-16 2       0.322594 -1.520035
​
```